# How To display column names as rows in Oracle PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have a query to get the count for some columns. 
I am  getting output with no errors but i need it in different way. 
Can someone help me to get the below output in Oracle Pl/SQL?

```
SELECT   
SUM (DECODE(COLUMN1,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT1,  
SUM (DECODE(COLUMN2,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT2,  
SUM (DECODE(COLUMN3,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT3,  
SUM (DECODE(COLUMN4,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT4,  
SUM (DECODE(COLUMN5,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT5,  
SUM (DECODE(COLUMN6,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT6   
FROM TABLE_NAME  
WHERE COLUMN7 IN ('X','Y');

 **OUTPUT:**  
-----------------------------------------
COUNT1|COUNT2|COUNT3|COUNT4|COUNT5|COUNT6
-----------------------------------------
5500  | 1245 | 5245 | 5675 | 7845 | 5324
-----------------------------------------

**Required Output**

COUNT1 | 5500  
-------------
COUNT1 | 1245 
-------------
COUNT1 | 5245 
-------------
COUNT1 | 5675 
-------------
COUNT1 | 7845 
-------------
COUNT1 | 5324
-------------
```

Comment: If you use Oracle why did you tag this question with sql server and mysql?

Comment: Is there any problem to use those tags? some people has knowledge on both. So i added those tags. Cant we use like this here because i am new to this forum.

Comment: You should only add tags relevant to the question, not to attract more people.

Comment: I removed the PL/SQL tag as it seems you are not looking for a stored procedure or function, but for a plain SQL solution.

Comment: Use [`unpivot`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/UNPIVOT) or `union` (six times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION`:

```
SELECT 'Count1' AS "Count", SUM (DECODE(COLUMN1,'Y',1,0)) AS Total 
FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN7 IN ('X','Y')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Count2' AS "Count", SUM (DECODE(COLUMN2,'Y',1,0)) AS Total 
FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN7 IN ('X','Y')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Count3' AS "Count", SUM (DECODE(COLUMN3,'Y',1,0)) AS Total 
FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN7 IN ('X','Y')
UNION ALL
...
```

However, if you have a column to `group by`, you can just group by it and use the sum in one query.

---

**UPDATE:**

You can do this also by using `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT   
  SUM (DECODE(COLUMN1,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT1,  
  SUM (DECODE(COLUMN2,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT2,  
  SUM (DECODE(COLUMN3,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT3,  
  SUM (DECODE(COLUMN4,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT4,  
  SUM (DECODE(COLUMN5,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT5,  
  SUM (DECODE(COLUMN6,'Y',1,0)) AS COUNT6   
  FROM TABLE_NAME  
  WHERE COLUMN7 IN ('X','Y')
)
UNPIVOT
(
  Total
  FOR COL IN(COUNT1,COUNT2,COUNT3,COUNT4,COUNT5,COUNT6)
)
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e596/3)

Comment: Count1 is not a column name its alias name.

Comment: @signup I don't understand? I am not using `count1` as a column name, I am using it as a string literal.

Comment: Sry Bro, I got it now. Thank you very much:)

Comment: @signup - You're welcome, please accept the answer if you found it helpful

Comment: Sure bro, as i told above i am new to this forum thanks for letting me know this. and If you know, can you please help me to use pivot function for above output.?

Comment: @signup Yes sure, but you need `unpivot` not `pivot`, please check my updated answer.

Comment: @HuntGeo-  Thanks again bro. :)